# ¿Como crear inputs dinamicamente con javacript a partir de un json?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net

Hola espero me puedan ayudar ya que no puedo resolver este problema cualquier ayuda es bien recibida y gracias por adelantado.

Bien tengo un grid anidado(jqx nestedGrid) por lo que al expander una fila me retorna un json como el de abajo. Depende de la fila expandida este json puede cambiar por ejemplo puede tener 3 metricas o 4 pero como dije todo depende de la fila expandida.

```
var datos =  [{"Metrica":"Mensual", "Nombre":"Juan", "Puesto":"Operador", "Edad":23}, {"Metrica":"Quincenal", "Nombre":"Paco", "Puesto":"Constructor", "Edad":40}];
```

Ahora mi pregunta es:

**¿Como puedo recorrer el json y crear inputs dinamicamente para mostrar los datos del json en los inputs?**

Por cierto trabajo con columnas dinámicas es por ello que no accedo al json con los nombres de las propiedades.

Aquí coloco mi código del recorrido del json.

```
    $.each(datos, function(key, val) {
     $.each(datos[key], function(k, v) {                                       

       });
     console.log("------> ", 0, val);
   });
```

Comment: He revertido la edición porque no se deben editar las preguntas "para agregar nuevos requerimientos" porque ello invalidaría las respuestas dadas previamente. En lugar de editar la pregunta se debe publicar una nueva.

Answer (score 3):

Si te sirve de ayuda, el paso de **JSON a Javascript** se realiza así:

> Asegúrate de que la entrada de datos en JSON esté en JSON, porque sino el posterior análisis en Javascript con `JSON.parse()` te disparará un error sintáctico.

```
var string = '{"name": "Marcelo", "age": "20"}';
var Object = JSON.parse(string);
```

Teniendo esto, podemos pasar los datos a elementos `input`.

```js
var string = '{"name": "Marcelo"}';
var Object = JSON.parse(string);

function foo(param1, param2)
{
  var newInput, input, foo, bar;
  newInput = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(newInput);
  input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  
  foo = document.createAttribute('name');
  bar = document.createAttribute('value');
  
  foo.value = param1;
  bar.value = param2;
  
  input.setAttributeNode(foo);
  input.setAttributeNode(bar);
}

foo('name', Object.name);
```

Te recomiendo crear de forma estática los elementos `input` con valores nulos:

```html
<input name="" value="">
```

Posteriormente, añadir sus valores dentro de cada atributo con Javascript.

Comment: Hola @ortizlab gracias por la respuesta pero he editado la pregunta por nuevos requerimientos espero me puedas ayudar de antemano gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo crear otra pregunta con tu nueva duda, ¡un saludo!